# Label above the input box

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

EXAMPLE: https://imgur.com/a/jDLedU8 (Only works when i use @)

I have 2 input boxes and an effect that when I click inside the input the label goes up to visualize what I am going to write, when I type in the password input box the label goes up normally and only goes down when I delete what is written in the input, when I write in the input of the email and I click outside, the email label is on top of the text I wrote, can you guys help me please? I'm new at this.

HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="icon-close">
            <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
        </span>

        <div class="form-box login">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form action="#">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <input type="email" required>
                    <label>Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="lock-closed"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <input type="password" required>
                    <label>Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="remember-forgot">
                    <label><input type="checkbox"> 
                    Remember me</label>
                    <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
                <div class="login-register">
                    <p>Don't have an account? <a
                    href="#"
                    class="register-link">Register</a></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="form-box register">
            <h2>Registration</h2>
            <form action="#">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" required>
                    <label>Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <input type="email" required>
                    <label>Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="lock-closed"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <input type="password" required>
                    <label>Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="remember-forgot">
                    <label><input type="checkbox"> I 
                    agree to the terms & conditions</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
                <div class="login-register">
                    <p>Already have an account? <a
                    href="#"
                    class="login-link">Login</a></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: url('background2.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 99
}

.logo {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    user-select: none;
}

.navigation a {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.navigation a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -6px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform .5s;
}

.navigation a:hover::after {
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navigation .btnLogin-popup{
    width: 130px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 40px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.navigation .btnLogin-popup:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #162938;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 440px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid  rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    border-radius: 20px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform .5s ease, height .2s ease;
}

.wrapper.active-popup {
    transform: scale(1);
}

.wrapper.active {
    height: 520px;

}

.wrapper .form-box {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px;
}

.wrapper .form-box.login {
    transition: transform .18s ease;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.wrapper.active .form-box.login {
   transition: none;
   transform: translateX(-400px);
}

.wrapper .form-box.register {
    position: absolute;
    transition: none;
    transform: translateX(400px);
}

.wrapper.active .form-box.register {
    transition: transform .18s ease;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.wrapper .icon-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #242424;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}

.form-box h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

.input-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.input-box label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 500;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .5s;
}

.input-box input:focus~label,
.input-box input:valid~label {
    top: -5px;

}

.input-box input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding:  0 35px 0 5px;
}

.input-box .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 57px;

}

.remember-forgot {
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: -15px 0 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.remember-forgot label input {
    accent-color: #ffffff;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.remember-forgot a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.remember-forgot a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.btn {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background: #242424;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.login-register {
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 25px 0 10px;
}

.login-register p a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.login-register p a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I tried some things but I couldn't solve it. I just want the email label not to be inside what I typed in the input box when I click outside, just like the password label that is not on top of what I type when I click outside the window.

Comment: It would be easier to debug with a working example of what your issue is. I know you provided some code, but it doesn't render anything.

Comment: I put an example link on imgur

Comment: It's just CSS and HTML. I SPECIFIED that I'm new, I gave the code, the video what else do I need to receive help?

Comment: If you take the code provided, and put it into for example Codepen, it renders nothing. We got nothing to work with and nothing to debug. Videos and images generally aren't allowed, because they provide nothing to work with.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you describe more clearly what you want the correct behavior to be? I'm not sure what it's supposed to do, which makes it hard to give a definite answer for how to fix it